# Is there a way to find the common ratio with the sum and first value of a geometric sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Given a geometric sequence $U(n)$, its only known values are $U_{0}$, $S$ the sum of the geometric sequence till a certain $N$-th term.

Is it possible to find $q$ via the following sum equation:
$$
S = U_{0}\left(\frac{q^N - 1}{q - 1}\right)\;?
$$
To simplify what I'm trying to find, I have set the following variables:
$$
X = \frac{S}{U_{0}}.
$$
What I want to know is that given $X$ and $N$, can we find $q$ easily with the following equation:
$$
X = \frac{q^N - 1}{q-1}\;?
$$

Comment: I think this might me impossible since it usually involve higher polynomials (has degree more than 4)

Comment: @pie I see, that's what I was thinking as well, if it was possible to easily find it, I could write a sorting algorithm in $O(N)$ time complexity.

Comment: $X$ is monotonic in $q$ so you can use binary search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n \ge 5$, in general, there is no solution in radicals for $q$ in the equation $$x = \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}. \tag{1}$$  For smaller $n$, we can use the methods for solving low-order polynomials (e.g., quadratic, cubic, and quartic formulae).

However, we can quickly find a root of $(1)$ by employing Newton's method.  Let $$f(z) = z^n - 1 - x(z-1) = z^n - xz + (x-1). \tag{2}$$  Then $$f'(z) = nz^{n-1} - x,$$ and we have the recursion
$$z_{k+1} = z_k - \frac{f(z_k)}{f'(z_k)} = z_k - \frac{z_k^n - xz_k + (x-1)}{nz^{n-1} - x} = \frac{(n-1)z_k^n - (x-1)}{nz_k^{n-1} - x}. \tag{3}$$  We now need to make an initial guess $z_0$.  A natural choice is to suppose $x \approx q^n/q = q^{n-1}$, so that $$z_0 = x^{1/(n-1)}. \tag{4}$$  (We will assume $n > 1$ since the case $n = 1$ is trivial.)  Then we compute sucessive iterates of $z_k$ until we obtain convergence.

Here is an example.  Suppose $x = 3725$ and $n = 13$.  Then we choose $z_0 = 3725^{1/12} \approx 1.98424$ and we use $(3)$ to compute the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
k & z_k \\
\hline
0 & 1.98423842903653327007689553768 \\
1 & 1.90092746706785318059143692471 \\
2 & 1.86622449798215768509689978419 \\
3 & 1.86093724741670620970910598569 \\
4 & 1.86082688465257555395503309422 \\
5 & 1.86082683752952357276321384119 \\
6 & 1.86082683752951498527167126885 \\
7 & 1.86082683752951498527167126856 \\
8 & 1.86082683752951498527167126856 \\
\end{array}$$

Therefore $q \approx 1.86082683752951498527167126856$.  Now we test it:  $$\frac{(1.8608268)^{13} - 1}{1.8608268 - 1} \approx 3725.$$

Comment: Thanks @heropup, I don't think this can be easily used in the case of trying to sort an array of size N with random numbers. I am in IT and my goal with this is to have a sorting algorithm of $O(N)$ complexity. As this would take too many computations.

Comment: @Hadestructhor I'm not really sure what exactly you are trying to do, but I can say that it typically doesn't take very many iterations to get convergence of $z_k$.  It's not clear to me how the solution of this equation is related to a sorting algorithm.  Maybe you can present additional details in another question.

Comment: Actually $(q^n - 1)/(q- 1) = q^{n - 1} + \dots + 1$ is a polynomial of degree $n - 1$, so there is a solution in radicals for $n = 5$. It is also not obvious to me that the Galois group is not solvable for $n > 5$ since this is a very special polynomial.